# Restore windows XP or boot in virtual environment

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, system-restore

I would like to have some kind of setup where I install some thin OS and install Windows on top of that (via virtual machine), so that I can restore Windows at any point.

Is that possible?

If not is there any other way other than system restore to do this. I always need to get the fresh copy of Windows when ever I feel the need to restore.

Comment: Yes it can be done these links may help.    
http://superuser.com/questions/279429/convert-virtualbox-guest-into-main-os   
http://superuser.com/questions/321691/minimal-os-for-running-virtual-machines

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to run some kind of hypervisor solution to do this but is there any reason why you're not just imaging your installation to an external hard drive in a known good state that you can restore from?  Something like clonezilla or ghost with a USB hard drive is the simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: in virtual environments just with one click I can take snapshots, so I like that feature

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a small partition and copy the setup dvd onto that.  You just modify the bootloader to let you boot into the DVD as well, so if you install goes FUBAR, you can boot into Setup without getting a setup DVD.